# Prime/undecomposable matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, nt.number-theory, reference-request

Prime matrices as defined in the following paper [Prime matrices P. F. RIVETT AND N. I. P. MACKINNON](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3616179) carry over many properties of factorization as in natural numbers to matrices over the field of naturals.

I quote the following:

> A matrix in a set M of matrices is prime (naturally enough) if it is not the
> product of any other matrices in the set. We thought we would look for the
> prime matrices in the set M of all 2 x 2 matrices with entries in the non negative
> integers and with determinant 1. To our great surprise we discovered
> that: there are  only two primes, and any member of M (except I) can be uniquely factorized into a product of those two.

[EDIT (PLC): For some reason, there seems to be some confusion on which two matrices are in question.  They are as follows:]

$$ P = \left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{array} \right),\ \  Q = 
\left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array} \right) $$

***My question is whether there are any other resources on prime matrices and if there has been any generalization beyond 2x2 matrices. What mathematics will I need to pursue the subject further?***

I have only three journal articles:

1. *Marenich, V. E.*, [**On prime matrices over distributive lattices**](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10958-009-9727-1), J. Math. Sci., New York 164, No. 2, 260-271 (2010); translation from Fundam. Prikl. Mat. 14, No. 7, 157–173 (2008). [Zbl 1288.15041](https://zbmath.org/1288.15041).
2. *Wang, Qianhua; Zhang, Zhongjun*, [**Algorithm for obtaining the proper relatively prime matrices of polynomial matrices**](https://doi.org/10.1080/00207178708547392), Int. J. Control 46, 769–784 (1987). [Zbl 0634.65030](https://zbmath.org/0634.65030).
3. *Rivett, P. F.; Mackinnon, N. I. P.*, [**Prime matrices**](https://doi.org/10.2307/3616179). Math. Gaz. 70, No. 454, 257–259 (1986).

Please specify whether I can get the article/journal or book for free.

Thanks.

Comment: But these (I mean thw two matrices) are the two generators, $T=[1,1;0,1]$ and $S=[0,1;-1,0]$ of the modular group! Look at Wikipedia article or better in Serre's "Course in arithmetic".

Comment: These are $\textit{group}$ generators, their inverses aren't in the set. Cf my comment to coudy's answer. 

Comment: Victor, today you really puzzle me: if only nonnegative integers are allowed, then $S$ is missed, so what are the two prime matrices?! Well, if one considers only positive powers, then $T^{-1}$ has to be included as well. But having determinant 1, so staying inside the modular group has no analogy with the prime factorisation in $\mathbb Z$. I guess that the author is just curious...

Comment: T and its transpose seem to work: you can "simplify" any matrix in M by multiplying it (left or right) by the inverse of T or its transpose.

Comment: @Wadim. Thanks. 
I have found  Course in Arithmetic to be helpful in this regard.
But there it says S is [0,-1;1,0].... Never mind

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/24131/is-the-semigroup-of-nonnegative-integer-matrices-with-determinant-1-finitely-generated?

Comment: In effect, I am looking for sources like the one mentioned by Amy Glen.

Comment: Reposting a link mentioned in a previous [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/61064) so that it appears in the "Linked" questions list: [Is the semigroup of nonnegative integer matrices with determinant 1 finitely generated?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/24131)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a different point of view, you might like to take a look at Section 12.5 and Appendix A in the [free on-line version](http://iml.univ-mrs.fr/editions/preprint00/book/prebookdac.html) of the following book (in which you'll find some interesting open questions related to "prime matrices" of the type you described):

N. Pytheas Fogg, Substitutions in dynamics, arithmetics and combinatorics, Lecture Notes in Mathematics, vol. 1794, Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 2002.

Comment: Quite helpful!!

Comment: In this book, prime matrices are termed "undecomposable matrices "

Comment: The link to the "free on-line version" now redirects to the homepage of [Institut de Mathématiques de Marseille](http://www.i2m.univ-amu.fr/), but a snapshot is saved on the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20100530120915/http://iml.univ-mrs.fr/editions/preprint00/book/prebookdac.html). The article is also available at [doi:10.1007/b13861](https://doi.org/10.1007/b13861) ([Zbl 1014.11015](https://zbmath.org/1014.11015)).

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest to have a look at books on fuchsian groups, e.g. Beardon, "the geometry of discrete groups", or  S. Katok, 
"fuchsian groups".

They don't talk about primitive matrices in your sense, but really, that's just because that's not the terminology used in the field.

For example, the fact that any integer matrices can be expressed as a product of powers of finitely many elements,
is a consequence of the following general result.

The group $SL_2(Z)$ has finite covolume in $SL_2(R)$. That means that the volume of $SL_2(Z)\backslash SL_2(R)$ is finite, and that implies that $SL_2(Z)$ is finitely generated: there exists a finite number of generators such that 
any element in $SL_2(Z)$ is a product of positive powers of these generators. There may be several ways to express an element in term of these generators, though.

Any discrete subgroup of $SL_2(Z)$ with finite covolume is in fact finitely generated. Uniqueness of the decomposition is not always granted, one has to dive a little deeper into the structure of $SL_2(Z)$ to understand why that holds in that particular case. Let me point out two remarkable properties of that group that ultimately explain why there is uniqueness.
First the two standard generators are conjuguated to their inverses, and that allows to take positive powers in the decomposition. And second, $SL_2(Z)$ contains a subgroup of index six which is a free group, so that uniqueness holds trivially for that subgroup. That subgroup is the set of integer matrices that are congruent to the identity modulo 2.

So I think you can get much insight from these books, even if they don't talk about primitive matrices per se.

Comment: You are missing the point: OP's matrices have $\textit{non-negative}$ entries (even if he mistakenly spoke of "FIELD of naturals"), and in semigroups, almost nothing works in the same way as in groups. E.g. there was a recent MO discussion of the fact that non-negative integer matrices for $n\geq 3$ are not f.g.

Comment: @Victor. My question was not addressing if the decomposition holds in higher dimension, but if it holds for *fuchsian* groups, for example for the subgroups of $SL_2(Z)$ obtained from the congruence subgroups. Let me be more specific. You can't have such decomposition for the derived subgroup of the principal congruence subgroup of level 2 because that group is infinitely generated. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: Right! I was a bit hasty. Not "the field of naturals" just the naturals.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to why this is the accepted answer.  The question is about free monoids and this answer discusses not necessarily free groups.  

Answer (score 1):

I got the results, which I'll describe below, for my own pleasure, without consulting anything, in 1971/2 in Ann Arbor, then I had a private seminar for a few kids at the U. of Texas at Austin in the fall of 1972, nothing official. The main topic was an elementary theory of diophantine approximations. Otherwise, I considered these things to be well known and even classic hence it was an end of the story to me. (I feel that Minkowski knew these things anyway). I also learned casually that there is some knowledge of this topic in computer science.

Let $\ SL(Z_{\ge 0})\ $ be the monoid of matrices with non-negative integer entries, which have determinant equal 1.

**THEOREM** $\ SL(Z_{\ge 0})\ $ is a free monoid which has a $2$-element free base
consisting of
$$ L\ :=\ \left[\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0\\ 1 & 1\end{array}\right]\qquad
   \mbox{and}\qquad R\ :=\ \left[\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1\\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right]. $$

**PROOF** (*a sketch*) Consider the infinite table:

$$ \left[\begin{array}{cccccccccccccccc}
 1/0 &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& 0/1 \\ 1/0 &&&&&&&& 1/1 &&&&&&&& 0/1 \\
 1/0 &&&& 2/1 &&&& 1/1 &&&& 1/2 &&&& 0/1 \\
 1/0 && 3/1 && 2/1 && 3/2 && 1/1 && 2/3 && 1/2 && 1/3 && 0/1 \\
 1/0 & 4/1 & 3/1 & 5/2 & 2/1 & 5/3 & 3/2 & 4/3 & 1/1
                         & 3/4 & 2/3 & 3/5 & 1/2 & 2/5 & 1/3 & 1/4 & 0/1 \\
\end{array}\right] $$
etc.

It's a pleasant(!) exercise to show that every matrix $\ M\in SL(Z_{\ge 0})\ $
appears in the above table in exactly one row, in an exactly one place -- just
remove the quotient signs ''$/$'', treat each fraction as a 2-dimensional (vertical) vector.

Observe that the fractions in each row go down from $\ \infty\ $ to $\ 0.\ $ I call a pair of such fractions (always reduced in this table) to be neighbors. Any reduced fraction which is between two neighbors has its denominator equal at least the sum of the denominators of the said neighbors.

**End of Proof** (well, of the sketch).

**REMARK** *I saw later a computer science text which features the above table, and a name was attached to this table.*

**REMARK** I remember that in one of the 2 volumes of *Development of the Minkowski Geometry of Numbers* by Harris Hancock, there was one line of the above table, perhaps only the half of the line between $0/1$ and $1/1$ (in this order, I think, which is reverse to the order above). I have a feeling that Minkowski knew what I have learned and you can see right now, that there is an increasing function of $[0;\infty]$ onto itself which maps non-negative rational numbers of the form $\ k/2^n\ $ onto the entire set of non-negative numbers $\ \mathbb Q_{\ge 0}\ := \mathbb Q\cap[0;\infty],\ $ and that this mapping maps $\ \mathbb Q_{\ge 0}\ $ onto the set of all non-negative numbers consisting of the rational numbers and of quadratic irrationals.

**REMARK** *This table is **very** closely related to continued fractions (another exercise).*

> I don't know any references but for the two mentioned above (about Minkowski and a computer science textbook) -- sorry for this.

Answer (score 0):

One can consider an alternative concept of  prime  matrix as follows:

A matrix $A\in M_n(\mathbb{Z})$ is prime if for any factorization $A=BC$ we have either $Det(B)\in \{-1,1\}$ or $Det(C)\in \{-1,1\}$. So we may ask for  existence of a singular prime matrix thanks to the fact that  every singular matrix is a product of idempotents . On the other hand one may investigate the question of uniquness of factorization of elements of $M_n(\mathbb{Z})\cap GL(n,\mathbb{R})$, module $\pm SL(n,\mathbb{Z})$.